# Examples of actions of algebras on categories

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, higher-category-theory, representation-of-algebras

I am trying to learn about actions of groups/algebras on categories. Below is a paragraph from the Preface to "Categorification and higher representation theory", it is the final sentence I wish to understand further:

> Categorified representation theory, or higher representation theory, aims to understand
>   a new level of structure present in representation theory. Rather than
>   studying actions of algebras on vector spaces where algebra elements act by linear
>   endomorphisms of the vector space, higher representation theory describes the
>   structure present when algebras act on categories, with algebra elements acting
>   by functors. The new level of structure in higher representation theory arises by
>   studying the natural transformations between functors. **Often these natural transformations
>   can be systematically described as representations of some monoidal
>   category that categorifies the original algebra.**

Does someone have an explicit example illustrating the phenomena that the final sentence is referring to?

Additionally, I am looking for introductory texts on this area, as I only have a passing knowledge of groups acting on categories, and for instance do not know what is meant by a "representation of a monoidal category".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most beautiful examples is the following: let $F$ be a field, let $n$ be a positive integer, let $S_n$ be the symmetric group, and let $R_n=S_n\text{-mod}$ be the category of $F$-linear representations of $S_n$. We have a bi-adjoint pair of induction and restriction functors $F:R_n \to R_{n+1}$ and $E:R_{n+1} \to R_n$. It is, of course, fruitful to study all the categories $R_n$ together with these functors.

Here is how the natural transformations arise (naturally!): the centralizer algebra $Z_{F S_{n+1}}(F S_n)$ is the algebra of endomorphisms of $E$ (and also of $F$). The *Jucys-Murphy-Young* element 
$$\phi_{n+1}=\sum_{i=1}^n (i,n+1)$$ is evidently an element of this centralizer algebra, and hence defines an endomorphism of $E$ (and of $F$). Together with the simple transpositions $(i,i+1)$, which give endomorphisms of $E^2$ (and $F^2$), these generate the action of a degenerate affine Hecke algebra by natural transformations on the functors $E^m$ and $F^m$ (for each positive integer $m$).

Moreover decomposing $E=\sum E_i$ into eigen-functors for $\phi_{n+1}$ produces what's usually referred to as a categorical representation of an affine Lie algebra (here, the action of the Hecke algebra via natural transformations is usually built into the axioms---keyword: *quiver Hecke algebra* or *Khovanov-Lauda-Rouquier algebra*).